# How to get the id of most recent polls in drupal

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to make frontpage and want to show most recent poll in block programmatically. I know that a block can be placed programmatically as:

```
     $block = module_invoke('block','block_view', 4);
      print render($block['content']);
```

And now I am unable to work out how get the most recent polls id.
I have tried('recent')  but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $block = module_invoke('poll', 'block_view'); ?>
<?php print render($block['content']); ?>
```

The module_invoke function requires only 2 paramenters, the first is the module name (poll) and the second is the hook. The delta is not necessary because poll_block_info() defines only one block so there's no need to pass a delta argument (just leave the 3rd argument out)